# How to fill missings in paneldata grouped by unit and time?

Tags: r, dplyr, missing-data, imputation, panel-data

I have panel data. In questionnaires (presumbly non-changing) data is sometimes not asked in each wave. A good example is gender. Let's assume I have data of a person for 3 periods, but only observed the gender once. It can be in any period. Missings are at random, they can be anywhere in the column.

```
paneldata = data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), time=seq(1:3), gender=c(1,1,1,2,NA,2,1,NA,NA))
library(dplyr)
paneldata %>% group_by(id,time)
```

I need to find something like "by unit and time: copy the value you find anywhere in the column in all NA-fields".

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *id+time* group contains only the NA you're looking to replace, so I assume you want a replacement from the *id* group.

Here's how to replace all values in the group with the first non-missing observation.

Edit: shs has a better solution in the comments below. Note that non-missing values are replaced as well so make sure that the variables are in fact non-changing.

```
    paneldata %>%
      group_by(id) %>%
      mutate(gender = first(na.omit(gender)))

    # A tibble: 9 x 3
    # Groups:   id [3]
         id  time gender
      <dbl> <int>  <dbl>
    1     1     1      1
    2     1     2      1
    3     1     3      1
    4     2     1      2
    5     2     2      2
    6     2     3      2
    7     3     1      1
    8     3     2      1
    9     3     3      1
```

Comment: That's it. Need to go deeper into `dplyr` :) Thank you

Comment: If he has many such variables, a more concise approach would be `paneldata %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate_at(c("gender"), ~first(na.omit(.)))`

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that the command takes long time to be executed with my dataset. Furthermore "'haven_labelled' elements may not preserve their attributes".